# Bootstrap Table cell color based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using Bootstrap tables from this site [Bootstrap Tables](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn) and I return data to the table from my MongoDB.

One of the fields is "ACTIVE" and i want to set the cell color based on the value returned in the field. If it is "YES" I want the cell to be green, and red for "NO".

Any help would be appreciated!!
Thanks

Comment: your script please

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is really simple. See the wenzhixin's own [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/9/) for cell styling

> bootstrap-tables has a function for cell customization name `cellStyle`

JavaScript:

```
function cellStyle(value, row, index) {
    return {
        classes: value.trim() === 'YES' ? 'yes' : 'no'
    };
}
```

Css:

```
td.yes {
  background-color: green;
}
td.no {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```js
function cellStyle(value, row, index) {
  return {
    classes: value.trim() === 'YES' ? 'yes' : 'no'
  };
}
```

```css
td.yes {
  background-color: green;
}
td.no {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<table data-toggle="table" id="demo-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-cell-style="cellStyle">Active</th>
      <th>Stars</th>
      <th>Forks</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="tr-id-1" class="tr-class-1">
      <td id="td-id-1" class="td-class-1">YES
      </td>
      <td>526</td>
      <td>122</td>
      <td>An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3)
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-2" class="tr-class-2">
      <td id="td-id-2" class="td-class-2">
        YES
      </td>
      <td>288</td>
      <td>150</td>
      <td>A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-3" class="tr-class-3">
      <td id="td-id-3" class="td-class-3">
        NO
      </td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-4" class="tr-class-4">
      <td id="td-id-4" class="td-class-4">
        YES
      </td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>my blog</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-id-5" class="tr-class-5">
      <td id="td-id-5" class="td-class-5">
        NO
        <td>6</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Redmine notification tools for chrome extension.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I'm still new to Javascript, and I had seen the reference, but couldn't figure it out the way you did.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but since I'm trying to learn Javascript - what would the statement look like if I wanted to evaluate three conditions, such as YES, NO, and MAYBE?

Comment: Perfect!! Than you Parvez - appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Most powerful and easy technique is using css,
i think you are using a code for generating tables, so if it said yes add a class to that element or simply add 'success' class, and for no add another class or just 'danger'. It will work simply and better than above, no js, and other things.

Comment: In Bootstrap 4, the class name for the `td` needs to be prefixed with `table-`, so  the above example should read `table-danger`. There are also `bg-` styles with the same name, but the colors are different.